# query to make the data grouped

Tags: sql

i have some data like this

```
datetime              value
2012-01-01 16:21:52     6
2012-01-01 16:22:02     5
2012-01-01 16:22:12     2
2012-01-01 16:22:22     3
2012-01-01 16:22:32     6
2012-01-01 16:22:42     9
2012-01-01 16:22:52     1
2012-01-01 16:23:02     3
2012-01-01 16:23:12     16
2012-01-01 16:24:02     7
2012-01-01 16:24:12     2
2012-01-01 16:24:22     6
2012-01-01 16:24:32     1
2012-01-01 16:24:42     8
2012-01-01 16:24:52     12
2012-01-01 16:25:02     15
2012-01-01 16:25:12     41
2012-01-01 16:25:22     29
2012-01-01 16:25:32     6
2012-01-01 16:25:42     6
2012-01-01 16:25:52     20
2012-01-01 16:26:02     10
2012-01-01 16:26:12     16
2012-01-01 16:26:22     14
2012-01-01 16:26:32     10
2012-01-01 16:26:42     6
2012-01-01 16:26:52     9
2012-01-01 16:27:02     7
2012-01-01 16:27:12     7
2012-01-01 16:27:22     17
```

i need a query to group the data with the condition of value < 10
i need as the result below

```
from                     to                   count
2012-01-01 16:21:52     2012-01-01 16:23:02     8
2012-01-01 16:24:02     2012-01-01 16:24:42     5
2012-01-01 16:25:32     2012-01-01 16:25:42     2
2012-01-01 16:26:42     2012-01-01 16:27:12     4
```

i wonder how it's possible to get the range of and count of data in groups which "value" are less than 10

Comment: and 3). this is something you should do in the code while iterating the result-set, not in your query.

Comment: @alfasin - Not true, if the OP can use `ROW_NUMBER()` this is perfectly suited to SQL, and quite simple to do.

Comment: @Dems: i'm using sql server 2008

Answer (score 2):

This is much more simply solved if you have access to `ROW_NUMBER()`.
- This exists in more recent versions of Oracle, SQL Server, etc
- It does not exist in MySQL

*Please confirm which RDBMS you are using.*

If you do have access to `ROW_NUMBER()` here is an approach...

```
WITH
  gaps_and_islands AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN value < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as is_island,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (                                                    ORDER BY value) AS land_level,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN value < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY value) AS water_level
  FROM
    yourData
)
SELECT
  is_island,
  MIN(datetime_field)    AS from_datetime,
  MAX(datetime_field)    AS to_datetime,
  COUNT(*)               AS count_of_rows
FROM
  gaps_and_islands
GROUP BY
  is_island,
  (land_level - water_level)
ORDER BY
  MIN(datetime_field)
```

This is a very novel approach the first time you look a it.  So I'll show you how it work by appending to your data...

```
datetime              value   land_level  water_level  (land_level-water_level)
2012-01-01 16:21:52     6          1             1                0
2012-01-01 16:22:02     5          2             2                0
2012-01-01 16:22:12     2          3             3                0
2012-01-01 16:22:22     3          4             4                0
2012-01-01 16:22:32     6          5             5                0
2012-01-01 16:22:42     9          6             6                0
2012-01-01 16:22:52     1          7             7                0
2012-01-01 16:23:02     3          8             8                0
2012-01-01 16:23:12     16         9            (1)              (8)
2012-01-01 16:24:02     7         10             9                1
2012-01-01 16:24:12     2         11            10                1
2012-01-01 16:24:22     6         12            11                1
2012-01-01 16:24:32     1         13            12                1
2012-01-01 16:24:42     8         14            13                1
2012-01-01 16:24:52     12        15            (2)             (13)
2012-01-01 16:25:02     15        16            (3)             (13)
2012-01-01 16:25:12     41        17            (4)             (13)
2012-01-01 16:25:22     29        18            (5)             (13)
2012-01-01 16:25:32     6         19            14                5
2012-01-01 16:25:42     6         20            15                5
2012-01-01 16:25:52     20        21            (6)             (15)
2012-01-01 16:26:02     10        22            (7)             (15)
2012-01-01 16:26:12     16        23            (8)             (15)
2012-01-01 16:26:22     14        24            (9)             (15)
2012-01-01 16:26:32     10        25           (10)             (15)
2012-01-01 16:26:42     6         26            16               10
2012-01-01 16:26:52     9         27            17               10
2012-01-01 16:27:02     7         28            18               10
2012-01-01 16:27:12     7         29            19               10
2012-01-01 16:27:22     17        30           (11)             (19)
```

The `land_level` just gives every sequential record a row id starting at 1.

The `water_level` is the same, except that there are two lists (partitions).
- All records where `value` is `<  10` get their own sequential ids starting at 1.
- All records where `value` is `>= 10` get their own sequential ids starting at 1.

*(This can be more easily seen because I put () around the `water_level` where `value` is `>= 10`)*

The 'trick' is then what happens when you take one away from the other.  You get a unique identifer for all the records that are next to each other in the same gap or island.

Comment: You can add a condition to the main `SELECT`: `WHERE value < 10` which can make your life easier. And I give your answer +1 only because you consider this solution "easy" :P

Comment: @alfasin - I left the `WHERE value < 10` out of the outer query, just so the OP can more clearly see what is being done.  So, yes, for exactly what the OP wants, it should indeed be added.

Comment: i need just the exact out put i mentioned. please tell me other ways to get the output i prefer!

Comment: @AliAhmadi - Did you try the query?  It should indeed give you the results you asked for.  *(The example data I gave was to show how it works, not what the final output is.)*  If it does not give you the output you desire, please could you describe what you are getting, and details as to how it is wrong?

Comment: as i said, i'm using sql server 2008 and the "Over" statement is not acceptable

Comment: @AliAhmadi - `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY x ORDER BY y)` was introduced in SQL Server 2005.  This should work fine in SQL Serve 2008.

Answer (score -1):

```
select
from = min(datetime),
to = max(datetime),
count = count(*)
from table_name
where value < 10
group by value
```

One thing to note, these column names probably won't work as these are DB keywords.

Comment: If you check the OP's example data, this grouping is *nothing* like what the OP asked for.  This is a Gaps and Islands problem.  The first island of data are all the rows up to, but not including, the first row where the value is greater than 9.